# Gradle deployment fails with "java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, deployment, build

I'm onboarding new developers to our Java code, but I'm running into an error in Windows. Most Gradle commands work fine, but our deployment command (dpDeployAll) fails. I followed same setup process on 3 different Windows machines; two Win10 machines face this error, Win7 machine does not.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
$ gradle dpDeployAll -Phost=10.2.9.106 --stacktrace
:deploy:checkJavaVersion UP-TO-DATE
:deploy:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:deploy:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:deploy:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:deploy:classes UP-TO-DATE
:deploy:dpDeployAll

ChargeAdmin servlet version on 10.2.9.106 is 1.3.1

Using profile all_production
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.Win32FileSystem.canonicalize(Win32FileSystem.java:414)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java_io_File$getCanonicalPath$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at deploy.Deploy$_runDeploy_closure7.doCall(Deploy.groovy:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2056)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$162.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at deploy.Deploy.runDeploy(Deploy.groovy:161)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
    at deploy.Deploy.runDeployProfile(Deploy.groovy:144)
    at deploy.Deploy.run(Deploy.groovy:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at deploy.Deploy.main(Deploy.groovy:335)
:deploy:dpDeployAll FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':deploy:dpDeployAll'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':deploy:dpDeployAll'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:369)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.258 secs
```

Edit: adding deploy.gradle file:

```
version '3.8.0'

apply plugin: 'groovy'

dependencies {
    compile localGroovy()
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.5.3'
    compile group: 'com.github.inamik.text.tables', name: 'inamik-text-tables', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse', name: 'org.eclipse.osgi', version: ECLIPSE_OSGI_VERSION
}

['dpDeployAll', 'dpDeploy', 'dpDeployAllCustom', 'dpList', 'dpUninstall', 'dpUninstallAll'].each { name ->
    //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
    task "$name"(type: JavaExec) {
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        main = 'deploy.Deploy'
        //noinspection GrUnresolvedAccess
        doFirst {
            if (project.hasProperty('host')) {
                arguments.add(0, project.getProperty('host'))
            } else {
                throw new InvalidUserDataException("Missing host property: specify with \"-Phost=hostname\"")
            }
            //noinspection GrUnresolvedAccess,GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            args arguments
        }
    }
}

dpDeployAll {
    doFirst {
        ext.arguments = ['deploy_all']
        arguments += ['all_production']
    }
}


dpDeploy {
    doFirst {
        ext.arguments = ['deploy']
        if (project.hasProperty('package')) {
            def packageName = project.getProperty('package')
            arguments += [packageName]
        } else {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("Missing packageName property: specify with \"-Ppackage=package\"")
        }
    }
}

dpUninstall {
    doFirst {
        ext.arguments = ['uninstall']
        if (project.hasProperty('package')) {
            def packageName = project.getProperty('package')
            arguments += [packageName]
        } else {
            throw new InvalidUserDataException("Missing packageName property: specify with \"-Ppackage=package\"")
        }
    }
}

dpUninstallAll {
    doFirst {
        ext.arguments = ['uninstall_all']
    }
}

dpList {
    doFirst {
        ext.arguments = ['list']
    }
}
```

Edit: adding deploy.groovy file:

```
package deploy

import com.inamik.text.tables.Cell.Functions
import com.inamik.text.tables.GridTable
import com.inamik.text.tables.grid.Border
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator
import groovyx.net.http.Method
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody

class Deploy {
    private static final String DEPLOY_ALL = 'deploy_all'
    private static final String DEPLOY = 'deploy'
    private static final String UNINSTALL = 'uninstall'
    private static final String LIST = 'list'
    private static final String UNINSTALL_ALL = 'uninstall_all'

    private static final String ADMIN_USERNAME = 'REDACTED'
    private static final String ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'REDACTED'

    private static final String ADMIN_SERVLET_PREFIX = '/charge_admin'
    private static final String GET_PACKAGES_SERVLET = ADMIN_SERVLET_PREFIX + '/get_packages'
    private static final String UNINSTALL_PACKAGES_SERVLET = ADMIN_SERVLET_PREFIX + '/uninstall_package'
    private static final String UPLOAD_PACKAGE_SERVLET = ADMIN_SERVLET_PREFIX + '/upload_package'

    private static final String CHARGEADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'com.projectfw.charge.chargeadmin'

    private static final String PACKAGE_COLUMN_HEADER = "Package"
    private static final String OLD_VERSION_COLUMN_HEADER = "Old Version"
    private static final String NEW_VERSION_COLUMN_HEADER = "New Version"
    private static final String STATUS_COLUMN_HEADER = "Status"

    private static final String DEV_VERSION_STRING = "dev"

    private static final String UNINSTALLED_STATUS = "UNINSTALLED"
    private static final String NO_CHANGE_STATUS = "NO_CHANGE"
    private static final String INSTALLED_FRESH_STATUS = "INSTALLED_FRESH"
    private static final String OVERWRITTEN_STATUS = "OVERWRITTEN"

    private final HTTPBuilder http
    private final String[] args
    private final String command
    private final String host

    private DeploymentPackage chargeAdminPackage
    private List<DeploymentPackage> nonChargeAdminPackages

    private Deploy(String[] args) {
        this.args = args
        this.host = args[0]
        this.command = args[1]
        this.http = new HTTPBuilder(String.format("http://%s", host))
        http.auth.basic(ADMIN_USERNAME, ADMIN_PASSWORD)
    }

    private void run() {
        populateExistingPackages()
        println()
        println "ChargeAdmin servlet version on $host is ${chargeAdminPackage.getOldVersion()}"
        println()
        switch (command) {
            case DEPLOY_ALL:
                final String profileName = args[2]
                runDeployProfile(profileName)
                break
            case DEPLOY:
                final String packageName = args[2]
                runDeploySingle(packageName)
                break
            case UNINSTALL:
                final String packageName = args[2]
                runUninstall(packageName)
                break
            case LIST:
                runList()
                break
            case UNINSTALL_ALL:
                runUninstallAll()
                break
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown command $command")
        }
    }

    private void runUninstallAll() {
        if (nonChargeAdminPackages.size() == 0) {
            println "No packages to uninstall on $host"
        } else {
            nonChargeAdminPackages.each {
                uninstallSinglePackage(it.packageName)
            }
        }
        println()
        printStatusTable()
    }

    private void runList() {
        printStatusTable()
    }

    private void runDeploySingle(String packageName) {
        runDeploy(Arrays.asList(packageName), false, true)
    }

    private void runUninstall(String packageName) {
        uninstallSinglePackage(packageName)
        println()
        printStatusTable()
    }

    private void uninstallSinglePackage(String packageName) {
        if (nonChargeAdminPackages.find { it.packageName == packageName } == null) {
            println "WARNING: Package $packageName does not exist on $host"
        } else {
            http.request(Method.POST) { req ->
                uri.path = UNINSTALL_PACKAGES_SERVLET
                requestContentType = ContentType.URLENC
                body = [package: packageName]
            }
            DeploymentPackage packageUninstalled = nonChargeAdminPackages.find { it.packageName == packageName }
            packageUninstalled.setStatus(UNINSTALLED_STATUS)
            packageUninstalled.clearNewVersion()
            println "Uninstalled package $packageName version ${packageUninstalled.getOldVersion()}"
        }
    }

    private void runDeployProfile(String profileName) {
        File profile = new File(profileName + '.txt')
        println "Using profile $profileName"
        if (!profile.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Profile file ${profile.getCanonicalPath()} does not exist")
        }

        String contents = profile.getText('UTF-8')
        List<String> deploymentPackageNames = contents.tokenize('\n').asList()
        Collections.sort(deploymentPackageNames)

        deploymentPackageNames = deploymentPackageNames.findAll {
            !it.contains(CHARGEADMIN_PACKAGE_NAME)
        }
        runDeploy(deploymentPackageNames, true, false)
    }

    private void runDeploy(List<String> deploymentPackageNames, boolean deleteUnlistedPackages, boolean force) {
        List<DeploymentPackage> packagesToUninstall = new LinkedList<>()
        List<DeploymentPackage> packagesToInstallFresh = new LinkedList<>()
        List<DeploymentPackage> packagesToOverwrite = new LinkedList<>()

        if (deleteUnlistedPackages) {
            // First, uninstall packages which are on the server but which aren't in the profile.
            nonChargeAdminPackages.each {
                if (!deploymentPackageNames.contains(it.getPackageName())) {
                    packagesToUninstall.add(it)
                }
            }
        }

        deploymentPackageNames.each {
            File localPackageDir = new File("../$it/build/distributions")
            if (!localPackageDir.exists()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Build directory ${localPackageDir.getCanonicalPath()} does not exist")
            }

            File[] deploymentPackageVersionFiles = localPackageDir.listFiles()
            if (deploymentPackageVersionFiles.length == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Build directory ${localPackageDir.getCanonicalPath()} is empty")
            }

            // Collect all the versions in the directory
            DeploymentPackage[] deploymentPackageVersions = deploymentPackageVersionFiles.collect { File file ->
                String version = file.getName().substring(
                        file.getName().indexOf('-') + 1, file.getName().lastIndexOf('.'))
                String packageName = file.getName().substring(0, file.getName().indexOf('-'))
                DeploymentPackage deploymentPackageVersion = new DeploymentPackage(packageName)
                deploymentPackageVersion.setNewVersion(version)
                deploymentPackageVersion.setLocalPath(file.getCanonicalPath())
                deploymentPackageVersion
            }

            // Find the one with the highest version number
            DeploymentPackage highestVersionedDeploymentPackage = deploymentPackageVersions.max {
                it.getNewVersion()
            }

            // Find the one that already exists on the server that we are comparing to:
            DeploymentPackage existingOnServer = nonChargeAdminPackages.find {
                it.getPackageName() == highestVersionedDeploymentPackage.getPackageName()
            }

            if (existingOnServer == null) {
                // We need to upload the package for the first time
                packagesToInstallFresh.add(highestVersionedDeploymentPackage)
            } else if (existingOnServer.getOldVersion() != highestVersionedDeploymentPackage.getNewVersion()) {
                // Existing version on server doesn't equal candidate version, should replace,
                // even if candidate version is older.
                packagesToUninstall.add(existingOnServer)
                packagesToOverwrite.add(highestVersionedDeploymentPackage)
            } else if (existingOnServer.getOldVersion().getQualifier().contains(DEV_VERSION_STRING)) {
                // Existing version on server has the dev version qualifier, should replace,
                // even though the version numbers are identical.
                packagesToUninstall.add(existingOnServer)
                packagesToOverwrite.add(highestVersionedDeploymentPackage)
            } else if (force) {
                // Replace it no matter what.
                packagesToUninstall.add(existingOnServer)
                packagesToOverwrite.add(highestVersionedDeploymentPackage)
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(packagesToUninstall)
        Collections.sort(packagesToOverwrite)
        Collections.sort(packagesToInstallFresh)

        packagesToUninstall.each {
            uninstallSinglePackage(it.getPackageName())
        }

        packagesToOverwrite.each {
            uploadPackage(it)
            DeploymentPackage existing =
                    nonChargeAdminPackages.find { existing -> existing.getPackageName() == it.getPackageName() }
            existing.setNewVersion(it.getNewVersion())
            existing.setStatus(OVERWRITTEN_STATUS)
        }

        packagesToInstallFresh.each {
            uploadPackage(it)
            it.setStatus(INSTALLED_FRESH_STATUS)
            nonChargeAdminPackages.add(it)
        }

        println()
        printStatusTable()
    }

    private void uploadPackage(DeploymentPackage pkg) {
        File file = new File(pkg.getLocalPath())
        http.request(Method.POST) { req ->
            uri.path = UPLOAD_PACKAGE_SERVLET
            requestContentType = 'multipart/form-data'
            req.entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(file.bytes, file.getName()))
                    .build()
        }
        println "Deployed ${pkg.getPackageName()} version ${pkg.getNewVersion()}"
    }

    private void populateExistingPackages() {
        String packagesString = http.request(Method.GET) { req ->
            uri.path = GET_PACKAGES_SERVLET
            response.success = { resp, reader ->
                reader.getText().toString()
            }
            response.failure = { HttpResponseDecorator resp, reader ->
                if (resp.getStatus() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unauthorized -- is the ChargeAdmin servlet installed?")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: dpDeployAll is not a task defined in your code snippet, make it hard to debug. Also this seems to be a Java problem first, a gradle error second, so you might more easily find answers by looking for solutions to the Java exception. The most likely culprit seems to be bad usage of forward/backward slashes when creating a filename.

Comment: @tkruse thank you very much for responding. That was dumb of me to not include the dpDeployAll piece. I added our build.gradle file and readme for dpDeployAll to original post. Based on my Googling I agree about it being a Java issue, seemingly with file/folder names, but it's strange that the other Gradle commands and Windows 7 machine work. I haven't had much luck tracking down the Java issue since the error doesn't provide much detail and my lack of developer-ness limits by ability to debug. I did take a look at --debug, but didn't see anything more than what is in the stacktrace.

Comment: Could you also check the java and gradle versions used on the windows machines? Might not be a windows-version related problem.

Comment: Also, do you have access to deploy/Deploy.groovy? This should be a custom file, either in your buildSrc folder, or in the sources of a custom plugin. It would make things easier for you and us to see it, possibly you can add debug statements to it's source.

Comment: @tkruse Yes the Java and Gradle versions are the same between machines. We all downloaded the 1.7.80 JDK directly from Oracle's website and allowed our code's Gradle wrapper to install Gradle 3.3 upon import to IntelliJ. I will triple check both again tomorrow though. In the meantime I added deploy.groovy to original post (after struggling mightily to get under SO's text limit). Going through it myself now to see if anything jumps out. Thanks again.

Comment: you can probably delete build.gradle from the post. Instead, identify the line in Depliy.grooy causing the exception, and add `print` statements before it with the path used for debugging.

Comment: Also restore the first stacktrace, because it is these lines that are important: `at deploy.Deploy$_runDeploy_closure7.doCall(Deploy.groovy:164)`

Comment: it seems this line is causing exception: `throw new RuntimeException("Build directory ${localPackageDir.getCanonicalPath()} does not exist")`. This means you need to know the path, and if that path exists on both the Windows7 and Windows8 machines. Adding `print localPackageDir` before the if-block should give you the output

Comment: @tkruse removed build.gradle and refreshed full stacktrace. I had to snip most of my intro comments and the end of deploy.groovy, but that was just the section where it formats the results in a table in the command line. I will do your suggestions first thing in the morning. I wish I had brought one of the laptops home so I could try right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to enlist the dev who built this to take a look and, of course, he figured it out quickly. It was an issue with the line returns in that all_production.txt file. Thanks, Windows.

> Windows uses \r\n for line endings, and everyone else uses \n.
>
> The deployment profiles (the .txt files which specify which packages
>   to install) all use \n.
>
> However, Git for Windows has an option which can convert the line
>   endings to \r\n on checkout for better compatibility with certain
>   Windows software.
>
> If this option was enabled, it caused the deployment script to fail
>   because it was splitting on \n, which left the \r at the end of the
>   strings. This trailing \r was interfering with the path construction
>   code.
>
> The fix is to split on either \n or \r\n, which allows the script to
>   work regardless of which type of line feed it encounters.

These were the changes to the deploy.groovy file:

(1) This:

```
List<String> deploymentPackageNames = contents.tokenize('\n').asList()
```

To this...

```
List<String> deploymentPackageNames = contents.split("\\r?\\n").toList()
```

(2) This:

```
List<String> packageLines = packagesString.tokenize('\n').asList()
```

To this...

```
List<String> packageLines = packagesString.split("\\r?\\n").toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception you get seems to stem from these lines of code:

```
File localPackageDir = new File("../$it/build/distributions")
if (!localPackageDir.exists()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Build directory ${localPackageDir.getCanonicalPath()} does not exist")
}
```

So when printing this error, the exception occurs during `.getCanonicalPath()`.

Likely the given path "../$it/build/distributions" exists on your Windows 7 computers but not on your Windows 10 machine, with $it being one of the names from your all_production.txt.

Likely that name contains some characters that break Java's `getCanonicalPath()`, so you would probably get the same error on Windows7 if the folder did not exist there neither.

That folder is a build output folder, so likely you have to run another task to create that folder.

Comment: I added the print statement, which produced /build/distributions as you suggested. I then went through every subfolder from all_production.txt and each one had that directory with the appropriate .dp in it. Each .dp has a pretty plain file name of com.projectfw.charger.packagename-1.5.0.dp with no special characters other than the periods and dash. I'm going to look into more potential causes of the Java exception tomorrow and may try reaching out to the dev who originally built all this. Thanks again for all the suggestions! I will keep this post updated.

Comment: You get a false return for localPackageDir.exists(), so /build/distributions does not exist relative to your script. If the print produced `/build/distributions` from `../$it/build/distributions`, then $it pointed at this same folder the build.gradle is in, which seems odd.

Comment: just want to make sure you saw the answer. Thanks again for all the responses. Merry Christmas!